# getting specific items from menu wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In trying to build 2 linked menus, lets say the hierarchy is like this (In the menu options)

```
- A
 -- B
 -- C
 -- D
   -- D1
   -- D2
- A1
```

The first menu I want it to be fixed so I fetched it with 
`'depth' => 1,`.

And the second menu has to be change according the first menu (like if I press `A` it will show `B` and `C`  AND `D` only
and when I press `B` its still has to get open as `B`, `C`, `D` (same if I press `D1`). I think we got the point of how it should work. 
As I tried to build this, I only accoplishe to fetch the menu only when you choice from the main menu (Like `A` or `A1`).
but as you choice deeper in the depth menu its showing hi's childrens. (like if I choice `D` the sub-menu gets to be `D1` and `D2`) and I dont want it,
I tried to check in which depth the menu is, or get anything that will help me make this sort but I couldn't find anything.

here is some code:
the function:

```
function submenu_get_children_ids( $id, $items ) {

    $ids = wp_filter_object_list( $items, array( 'menu_item_parent' => $id ), 'and', 'ID' );

    foreach ( $ids as $id ) {

        $ids = array_merge( $ids, submenu_get_children_ids( $id, $items ) );
    }

    return $ids;
}
```

fetching the menu :

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu(array(
    'container' => false,                           // remove nav container
    'container_class' => 'right_menu',                 // class of container (should you choose to use it)
    'menu' => __( 'top_main_nav', 'bonestheme' ),  // nav name
    'menu_class' => 'main_bar_menu '.$lang.'',               // adding custom nav class
    'theme_location' => 'main-nav',                 // where it's located in the theme
    'before' => '',                                 // before the menu
    'after' => '',                                  // after the menu
    'link_before' => '',                            // before each link
    'link_after' => '',                             // after each link
    'depth' => 1,                                   // limit the depth of the nav
    'fallback_cb' => ''                             // fallback function (if there is one)
)); 


$current_page = 0;
// check if the current page has a menu.

foreach(wp_get_nav_menu_items('top_main_nav') as $pagec) {
    if(get_the_title() == $pagec->title) {
        $current_page = $pagec->title;
    }
}

if($current_page === 0) {
    $current_page = "Home";

}


$args = array(
    'container' => false,
    'container_class' => 'main_bar_menu',
    'menu'    => 'top_main_nav',
    'menu_class' => 'main_bar_menu',
    'submenu' => $current_page,
);
wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

I'm trying to find a solution about 2 days now :\ if someone could guide me with that i'd be so thankful!

thanks alot!